# laravel join fake table

Tags: laravel, datatable, query-builder

I'm using datatables with server side processing in a Laravel project. My status column is integer, which is then formatted

```
            ->editColumn('status', function($orders) use ($statuses) {
                return $statuses[$orders->status];
            })
```

But this approach prevents `status` column from being used in search.

Is sthere a way to join query with fake table? Smth like this

```
->join('fake_status_table', 'production_orders.status', '=', 'fake_status_table.id')
```

**Drafting two solutions**

Solution #1

```
$orders= DB::table('production_orders')
    ->select(DB::raw("DECODE (status_id, 1, 'No started', 
                                        2, 'Running', 
                                        3, 'Done', 
                                        4, 'Defect')"))
```

solution #2

```
    //create tamporary table
    $status_table = DB::insert( DB::raw( "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statuses") );
    $orders = \DB::table('production_requests')
            // join it with drawing table
            ->join('statuses', 'production_requests.status', '=', 'statuses.id')
    // Generate result
    $result = Datatables::of($orders)->make(true);
    // KILL TEMPORARY TABLE
    $dropTable = DB::unprepared( DB::raw( "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE statuses" ) );
    // RETURN RESULT
    return $result;
```

Comment: Why not using `views` ?

Comment: No. I'm using `yajra\Datatables\Datatables`

Comment: You shall try views which is a temporary table. You want to know about views with datatables ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Lol, I didn't know about SQL views. Thought you were refering to Larevel view. Sure, can you give me an example?

Comment: Okay, I will write answer in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

[Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) is nothing but a temporary table..

But it was copy of the table itself.. You shall create a view according to your need.. If you want to have the view of your entire table .. then

```
CREATE VIEW test.v AS SELECT * FROM t;
```

Or even

```
 CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;
```

Then you shall return some data from the controller and construct the coloumn as we do usual in the [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)

Like this

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

And then foreach for the table !!

Hope this helps you

Comment: ok, how do I use this `qty*price AS value FROM t` to replace integers with corresponding strings from `array`?

Comment: Could u explain a bit

Comment: In example you provided, contents for virtual column is created by where inputs are two other columns. In my case I need to replace integers in columns with strings `array(1 => 'No started', 
                                        2 => 'Running', 
                                        3 => 'Done', 
                                        4 => 'Defect')`

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok You mean to say. You want to hardcode the two values in your views ever ?

Comment: Not sure I get the question right, but, among others, the reason I'm using integers to specify status instead of strings is because, application is and needs to be translatable.